# Google Javascript API (gapi) - problems with .load

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am trying to use the Google plus API (via googie-api-javascript) implementation like so (omitting full code):

```
var clientId = '7454475891XxxxxxXom4c6n.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //fake client
var apiKey = '-uTH_p6NokbrXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //Fake Key
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

function handleClientLoad() {
   gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
   window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
   gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {        
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {          
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
    //handle user-approval
  }
}

  // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
      var o = gapi.client.plus;
      alert(o);
    });
}
```

The code works well upto the point of gapi.client.load (including the user allowing access) - this callback gets called but alert(o) will return undefined.

Upon inspecting the HTTP request I see the .load issues a request to:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/plus/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0&key=-uTH_p6NokbrXXXXXXXX
```

This returns HTTP 400 with the following message:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyInvalid","message":"Bad Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}
```

My question is - what do I need to change to make this work?
Is there some secret setting I need to enable ? Google+ is enabled in the google-developer-console under the APIs list.

Thanks for the help,
Alon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem:
.load issues a request to the google discovery service to load the .JS. The service will error out if the request it receives contains an api-key. (I don't know why the library works like this, it seems like a bug?)

Fix:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(""); //NEW
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function()
//re-add the key later if you need it
```

> From Discovery Service docs:
>   requests you make to the Discovery Service API should not include an API key. If you do provide a key, the requests will fail.

Weird... :P

Comment: Wow.. thanks so much, how would I have even found that! Especially since on the google documentation and example, they do provide one

Answer (score 2):

A little update & more of an explanation. The current [Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using) page is a little more specific now. They indicate that if the app has an Oauth2 token, then the API Key value is not required. ***However,*** I also found that if I have an authenticated user and thus an Oauth2 token (access_token) present, the Discovery Service fails with the error noted in the OP. This seems to contradict the documentation.

You can see the token in the developer tools console with:

```
console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse());
```

Embed that somewhere in a `<script>...</script>`in your HTML or in a .js file that is called otherwise. Must be after `gapi.load(...)`. It'll stop the script if executed before `gapi.load(...)` is called.

To get a current user this has to be ***after*** the user is authenticated, of course. It does return an object if a user has not been authenticated however. If you are in Chrome, you can expand The Object in the developer tools console window to get a nice outline format of all the stuff in the auth response.

Note that currentUser is undefined prior to a successful authentication. Since this 'fails silently' you should use a conditional statement to verify either the sign in status or that a current user exists in your real code.

For completeness the object instantiation process in my app goes like this, at a high level:

1.) `gapi.load(...)` - After this gapi.client, gapi.auth2 and other objects are available.

2.) `gapi.client.setApiKey("")` would be called to 'clear' the api key if it had been set previously for some other purpose.

3.) `gapi.auth2.init(...)` - After this the auth instance is available via `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance` .

4.) Then the login is kicked off using the `.signIn()` method of the auth instance. The auth instance would be instantiated with something like `auth_instance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();` If that's how you do it then the sign in would be `auth_instance.signIn()`.

(...) - *means there are several parameters needed.*

I also found the Google [tictactoe example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python.git) useful as an example and a simple base for further work.

I hope this is helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the method

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false} handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {
     gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
         var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
             'userId': 'me'
         });

         request.execute(function (resp) {
             'method ajax with you application'
         });
    });
}
```

you can see what this do [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html)